# Prevent swagger-codegen (OpenAPI 2.0) url-encoding of string format: URI

Tags: swagger, swagger-codegen, openapi

I have a problem where an OpenAPI 2.0 specification takes a path parameter that is a valid string URI which looks like `1234/models/4321/v1` to form a URL endpoint that looks like: `http://localhost/endpoints/1234/models/4321/v1/predict`. I've defined the endpoint as the following in my swagger.yaml:

```
/endpoints/{modelURI}/predict:
    post:
      operationId: predict
      summary: Run inference on the input array.
      consumes:
      - application/json
      produces:
      - application/json
      parameters:
      - name: body
        in: body
        description: The input NDArray
        required: true
        schema:
          $ref: '#/definitions/Prediction'
      - name: modelURI
        in: path
        description: The URI of the model
        required: true
        type: string
        format: uri
```

The problem is that event though I've specified `format: uri` Swagger codegen will URL-encode the path parameter in the generated clients and the request will look like `http://localhost/endpoints/1234%2Fmodels%2F4321%2Fv1/predict`. Lower in our software stack there's an HTTP router which cannot interpret the request because it's expecting a different format. Unfortunately due to legacy software, we cannot easily change the specification.

How can I instead force Swagger to not encode this path parameter? Can I do this through some sort of plugin?

Comment: Check out the linked questions. Slashes are currently not allowed in path parameters. There's an open feature request at https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/issues/892.

Comment: This question specifically points to a `format: uri` specification, however because the first link has an accepted answer I'll accept this as a duplicate. Thanks for linking them.